# Elasticsearch filter not filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the Elasticsearch query where I am trying to filter results that have a "source" of a specific kind but the query produces the same number of results regardless of the filter value.

```
{
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "source": "network"
                        }
                    },
                    "must": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "",
                            "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                            "type": "best_fields",
                            "fields": [
                                "body"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['body_vector'])"
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the source type to keyword but that didn't change anything.

The index mappings are below.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": "true"
        },
        "properties": {
            "body": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "body_vector": {
                "dims": 512,
                "type": "dense_vector"
            },
        },
        "dynamic": "true"
    }
}
```

Sample docs below.

```
{"body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean malesuada quis neque et volutpat. Integer sodales nec odio a suscipit. Morbi bibendum ut velit sed sagittis. Nulla id nibh porta, finibus tellus sit amet, dignissim eros. Nulla malesuada est mollis odio dignissim, in imperdiet quam ultricies. Proin velit velit, congue ut mollis sit amet, blandit id lorem. Sed interdum viverra augue. Nulla porttitor, elit sit amet euismod ultrices, libero lorem elementum ligula, eu facilisis urna enim sed purus. Proin tempor aliquam turpis. Nulla eget magna lectus. Donec ultricies erat eu tellus hendrerit dignissim.",  "filename": "Filename 1",  "source": "network",  "documenttype": "docx",  "lastmodified": "158262531",  "title": "" }
{"body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean malesuada quis neque et volutpat. Integer sodales nec odio a suscipit. Morbi bibendum ut velit sed sagittis. Nulla id nibh porta, finibus tellus sit amet, dignissim eros. Nulla malesuada est mollis odio dignissim, in imperdiet quam ultricies. Proin velit velit, congue ut mollis sit amet, blandit id lorem. Sed interdum viverra augue. Nulla porttitor, elit sit amet euismod ultrices, libero lorem elementum ligula, eu facilisis urna enim sed purus. Proin tempor aliquam turpis. Nulla eget magna lectus. Donec ultricies erat eu tellus hendrerit dignissim.",  "filename": "Filename 2",  "source": "network",  "documenttype": "docx",  "lastmodified": "158262531",  "title": "" }
{"body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean malesuada quis neque et volutpat. Integer sodales nec odio a suscipit. Morbi bibendum ut velit sed sagittis. Nulla id nibh porta, finibus tellus sit amet, dignissim eros. Nulla malesuada est mollis odio dignissim, in imperdiet quam ultricies. Proin velit velit, congue ut mollis sit amet, blandit id lorem. Sed interdum viverra augue. Nulla porttitor, elit sit amet euismod ultrices, libero lorem elementum ligula, eu facilisis urna enim sed purus. Proin tempor aliquam turpis. Nulla eget magna lectus. Donec ultricies erat eu tellus hendrerit dignissim.",  "filename": "Filename 3",  "source": "local",  "documenttype": "docx",  "lastmodified": "158262531",  "title": "" }
{"body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean malesuada quis neque et volutpat. Integer sodales nec odio a suscipit. Morbi bibendum ut velit sed sagittis. Nulla id nibh porta, finibus tellus sit amet, dignissim eros. Nulla malesuada est mollis odio dignissim, in imperdiet quam ultricies. Proin velit velit, congue ut mollis sit amet, blandit id lorem. Sed interdum viverra augue. Nulla porttitor, elit sit amet euismod ultrices, libero lorem elementum ligula, eu facilisis urna enim sed purus. Proin tempor aliquam turpis. Nulla eget magna lectus. Donec ultricies erat eu tellus hendrerit dignissim.",  "filename": "Filename 4",  "source": "local",  "documenttype": "docx",  "lastmodified": "158262531",  "title": "" }
```

The query should only return the first 2 documents where the source = network.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you provide your index mapping and some sample docs and expected documents?

Comment: Added the mapping. I won't be able to add any documents as this is for an internal search.

Comment: you can change the values of sample docs and provide them

Comment: Is that enough information?

Comment: then wht can't you simpy use the term filter query

Comment: How is that different to the query I’m currently using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209976/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-user1020496).

Comment: Please let me know if you have further questions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample mapping and documents and below search query, it returns onlt documents which contain `source` as `network`.

### Search query

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "source": "network" }} -> filter all docs which contains network in source field.
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Result

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_60746695_dsl",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean malesuada quis neque et volutpat. Integer sodales nec odio a suscipit. Morbi bibendum ut velit sed sagittis. Nulla id nibh porta, finibus tellus sit amet, dignissim eros. Nulla malesuada est mollis odio dignissim, in imperdiet quam ultricies. Proin velit velit, congue ut mollis sit amet, blandit id lorem. Sed interdum viverra augue. Nulla porttitor, elit sit amet euismod ultrices, libero lorem elementum ligula, eu facilisis urna enim sed purus. Proin tempor aliquam turpis. Nulla eget magna lectus. Donec ultricies erat eu tellus hendrerit dignissim.",
                    "filename": "Filename 1",
                    "source": "network",
                    "documenttype": "docx",
                    "lastmodified": "158262531",
                    "title": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "so_60746695_dsl",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean malesuada quis neque et volutpat. Integer sodales nec odio a suscipit. Morbi bibendum ut velit sed sagittis. Nulla id nibh porta, finibus tellus sit amet, dignissim eros. Nulla malesuada est mollis odio dignissim, in imperdiet quam ultricies. Proin velit velit, congue ut mollis sit amet, blandit id lorem. Sed interdum viverra augue. Nulla porttitor, elit sit amet euismod ultrices, libero lorem elementum ligula, eu facilisis urna enim sed purus. Proin tempor aliquam turpis. Nulla eget magna lectus. Donec ultricies erat eu tellus hendrerit dignissim.",
                    "filename": "Filename 2",
                    "source": "network",
                    "documenttype": "docx",
                    "lastmodified": "158262531",
                    "title": ""
                }
            }
        ]
```